# colour detection using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

```
#importing Modules

import cv2
import numpy as np

#Capturing Video through webcam.

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while(1):
        _, img = cap.read()

        #converting frame(img) from BGR (Blue-Green-Red) to HSV (hue-saturation-value)

        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        #defining the range of Yellow color
        yellow_lower = np.array([22,60,200],np.uint8)
        yellow_upper = np.array([60,255,255],np.uint8)

        #finding the range yellow colour in the image
        yellow = cv2.inRange(hsv, yellow_lower, yellow_upper)

        #Morphological transformation, Dilation         
        kernal = np.ones((5 ,5), "uint8")

        blue=cv2.dilate(yellow, kernal)

        res=cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = yellow)

        #Tracking Colour (Yellow) 
        (_,contours,hierarchy)=cv2.findContours(yellow,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
                area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
                if(area>300):

                        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)     
                        img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),3)

        cv2.imshow("Color Tracking",img)
        img = cv2.flip(img,1)
        cv2.imshow("Yellow",res)

        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == 27:
                cap.release()
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break
```

getting the error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "face.py", line 15, in <module>
>     hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
> cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181:
> ```
>
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function
>   'cv::cvtColor'

Answer (score 0):

If the assertion failed, that means that you are feeding cv::cvtColor an image that doesn't exist. Perhaps your camera is faulty, or you are locating the camera incorrectly. I would recommend first using your camera to generate an example video, then using running this program on the video before you attempt a live feed.